# get a file from an array and extract data

Tags: command-line, bash

Using an array I have gotten the output of a menu (something similar) as follows;

```
1 file_1101
2 file_1102   
3 file_1103 
4 file_1104
5 file_1105
```

The code

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a logs
order="acc_log.+csv$"
mennum=1

for file in ./*; do
    if [[ $file =~ $order ]]; then
        logs+=($(basename $file))
    fi
done

count=${#logs[*]}
echo -e "The logs array contains $count files.\n"

for file in "${logs[@]}"; do
    echo -e "$mennum $file"
    ((mennum++))
done
```

Now I want to extract columns from each of these files. How to extract the file using the cat command or if you suggest any other command that also will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own menu, you can use `select`

```bsh
select file in "${logs[@]}"; do
    printf 'You selected "%s"\n' "$file"
    break
done
cat "$file" # or do whatever with this file
```

Or without saving an intermediate array, which is not necessary in this case I think:

```bsh
select file in acc_log*.csv; do
    printf 'You selected "%s"\n' "$file"
    break
done
cat "$file" # or do whatever with this file
```